# Why an async validator callback won't have the component context?

Tags: angular, typescript

I noticed I didn't have access to the component from one of its methods, which I assigned to an async validator (simulated with a timeout).

So I needed to force its context by using bind(). Is it always this way with an async validator? Or is there anything else missing so that this method keeps the context where it belongs to?

Here's the code:

https://embed.plnkr.co/xJz7Z66SUUFaN8QCYcrJ/

Note the assignment of the validator with:

```
this.asyncExampleValidator.bind(this)
```

in data-driven.component.ts

Comment: I have understood that you should provide relevant code in post since links can change, just a suggestion :)

Comment: @ASomeOneJ: How can I embed a plunkr code here? I think I've seen it in other questions here in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can [Use Instance Functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#use-instance-functions)
to keep "this" where you want it to be

here

```
 onAddHobby() {
      (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('hobbies')).push(new FormControl('', Validators.required, this.asyncExampleValidator.bind(this)));
    }
```

onAddHobby "this" might not be what you expect
and asyncExampleValidator suffers the same

['**this**' in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript)

Comment: Didn't know anything about Instance Functions. I tried it instead of bind() and it works. However I feel more comfortable using bind(), even though they explain it like the less recommendable choice. Thanks for pointing me to that info.